# How to tell if bundle install is doing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, bundle, bundler

I have created a vagrant instance from hashicorp/precise64 and once I logged in via putty changed to vagrant directory I ran

```
bundle install --verbose
```

however the only output I have received is...

```
Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org
```

My gemfile has approximately 150 gems and my gemfile.lock has over 500 lines. There has been no other output for half an hour and I was wondering at what point should I accept that something is wrong. I assumed with verbose specified there would be some output but nothing has appeared. Any help would be appreciated as I'm not sure if I'm just wasting my time.

Update:

Subsequent to suggestions I ran "gem install rails" and received the following output:

```
Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.
```

Firstly why wouldnt I get some information like this returned on my bundle install and secondly should I change ownership of this directory or is there an issue with my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go with - something is wrong.  `bundle install --verbose` is the appropriate way to get the most information out of bundler when doing an install.  I would try something simpler, like a `gem install rails` and see if it works.  This will help diagnose if it's a networking issue.  Also try trimming down your Gemfile temporarily to see if it will complete with only say 10 gems.

Comment: Thanks. You've confirmed what I've thought but didnt want to assume in case I was being too hasty. Have ran "gem install rails" and nothing is being returned as of yet (5 minutes now). What could be the problem? Would it be my vagrant configuration or something else?

Comment: I'd be using rvm or rbenv in my vagrant box to manage ruby versions.

Answer (score 0):

Grant an access to `/opt` directory for your user, with:

```
chown -R `whoami` /opt
```

And try again